# ArrayList from a method with a counter++ variable

Tags: arraylist, static-variables

I need to call the method `student`, creating a student with a student ID that starts at 1 and increases with each new student, then take that new student and add it to an `ArrayList`. However, my list just gets the ID number that was last called and gives it to all members of the list. If I put in "James" with GPA 3.4 and "Jack" with GPA 2.9, it will return both students with the same student id of 2. I need help getting it to give James an ID of 1, Jack an ID of 2, and so on. The first block is from my `main` method and the second at the end is from the class itself.

```java
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
int option = -1;
String name;
double gpa;
Scanner studentInput = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner gpaInput = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner optionInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while (option != 0) {
    System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
    System.out.println("0: quit");
    System.out.println("1: Add a student to your list");
    System.out.println("2: Display your student list");
    option = optionInput.nextInt();
    switch (option) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Have a good Day!");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Please enter the students name.");
        name = studentInput.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the students GPA.");
        gpa = gpaInput.nextDouble();
        Student studentA = new Student(name, gpa);
        list1.add(studentA);
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Here is your list so far.");
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list1.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

```java
public class Student implements Comparable {
    private static int studentID = 0;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;

    public Student( String name, double gpa) {
        studentID++;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setGpa(double gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `studentID` field in your class is shared between all instances of `Student`, so if its value changes, `getStudentID` will return the new value for all instances. To fix this, add another non-static field for the student ID, then store the value of the static field into the field you just added in the constructor:

```java
public class Student implements Comparable {
    private static int globalStudentID;
    private int studentID;
    private String name;
    private double gpa;

    public Student( String name, double gpa) {
        globalStudentID++;
        this.studentID = globalStudentID;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    // ...
}
```